# How to set mat-option default value for a dropdown after clicking a button

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

```
<div class="form-group row margin-bottom-10">
          <div class="col-lg-3" style="margin-left:18px;">
            <input type="text" [formControl]="MSHRequestFormGroup.controls.MESWorkOrderControl"
              [matAutocomplete]="auto" placeholder="Select Work Order" 
              class="form-control height-64 border-r-round input-text-autocomplete">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWorkOrders">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of workOrderFilteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
                  {{option.WorkOrder}}
                </mat-option>
              <!-- </select> -->
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 p-2">
            <button type="button" mat-button (click)="onMESWorkOrders(); isClicked = true;" [disabled]="isClicked"
              style="background-color: rgb(65, 186, 28); color: white;">
              <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2 mb-1" role="status" *ngIf="isWait"></span>View Work
              Orders</button>
          </div>
 </div>


this.workOrders = this.response.Data;
this.workOrderControlOptions = this.workOrders;
this.MSHRequestFormGroup.controls['MESWorkOrderControl'].setValue(this.workOrderControlOptions[0].WorkOrder;
this.workOrderFilteredOptions = this.MESWorkOrderControl.valueChanges
              .pipe(
                startWith(),
                map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
                map(name => name ? this._filterWorkOrders(name) : this.workOrderControlOptions.slice())
                // tap(() => this.MSHRequestFormGroup.controls.MESWorkOrderControl.setValue(this.workOrderControlOptions[0].WorkOrder))
              );
```

Comment: Please use the stackoverflow code formatting so we can analyse your code more easily!